# Does the nav of (Indian) mutual funds with international/global commodities change during Indian public holidays?

Tags: india, mutual-funds

Consider the example of the funds in [this list](http://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/performance-tracker/returns/international-global-commodities.html). They all invest in international commodities. So, do their nav change even during Indian public holidays?

[I have observed in my Zerodha dashboard. It did not show any change on Oct 2, which is a public holiday.] But technically, their value should change, cause the international markets were open and trading that day.

**So, how does this work?  And does the nav change on those days?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The net asset value will in principle be changing all the time, 24 hours a day, 365 days a year. But it will only be calculated and reported to the markets when the people who do that work are at their desks and working.